# How can i take multiple url value in single variable name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In below I want to pass a variable value from one page to other using url redirection. But in my variable I have multiple url, so that when I click on particular url only that url value will store and redirected.

```js
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
   $('a').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var clk=$('#fkt').attr('href');
 var clk=$('#snd').attr('href');
 var clk=$('#amz').attr('href');
 //alert(clk);
 window.location='http://www.shopeeon.com?ver='+clk;

 });
});
</script>

<a id='fkt' href="http://www.google.com">Google</a><br/>
<a id='snd' href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a><br/>
<a id='amz' href="http://www.rediff.com">Rediff</a><br/>
```

In my case it will only take last URL link and stored in `clk` variable.

Comment: Use `$(this).attr('href')` in the `click` handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't work is, you are redeclaring the same string again and again, and it wipes out old content. You may use this:

```
var clk = $('#fkt').attr('href');
clk += $('#snd').attr('href');
clk += $('#amz').attr('href');
```

This concatenates the string.

Can you use an array?

```js
var clk = [];
clk.push($('#fkt').attr('href'));
clk.push($('#snd').attr('href'));
clk.push($('#amz').attr('href'));

console.log(clk.join(","));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id='fkt' href="http://www.google.com">Google</a><br/>
<a id='snd' href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a><br/>
<a id='amz' href="http://www.rediff.com">Rediff</a><br/>
```

You should use the contextual `this`. But ultimately, what you are looking for is:

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var clk = $(this).attr('href');
  location.href = 'http://www.shopeeon.com?ver='+clk;
});
```

Comment: actuall i have lots of a href but i could not perform onclick action on every link that's why i can't use "this" suggest some other way

Comment: I also use above array method,by using this it will redirect with all three links instead one at a time

Comment: @shopeeon Yea, it was confusing. So gave you three different answers. You can choose the one that's best for you.

Answer (score 1):

To get the `href` of the current clicked `<a>` tag use `this`:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var clk = $(this).attr('href');
    window.location='http://www.shopeeon.com?ver='+clk;
});
```